# Css and js not loading in admin page

Tags: magento-1.9

I have installed magento1.9.2 but the admin page is not loading properly.  The Css and Java script is not loading.

Comment: Welcome to Magento SE. Take a look at the HTML source code of the page. If you see the CSS/JS files referenced with file system paths, see linked duplicate. If not, please update your question with details.

Comment: you may have some wrong URL configuration, take a look at your core_config_data table and check the path values, like web/unsecure/base_skin_url

Answer (score 1):

Please check the permissions of folders:

var
Media
includes

all above must have 777 permission.

open ssh of folder and traverse to root of magento project

run below command:

chmod -R 777 var

chmod -R 777 media

chmod -R 777 includes

Even if css not loading then open the source and check the css links are opening or not.

Comment: Thank you, can you please elaborate me with the steps as I'm in the process of learning

Comment: I have updated answer please check.

Comment: No, Css links are not working...